# How would you read the data from a TIF image in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I would like to process Landsat8 raw data with OCaml. The data is stored in TIF files. An example of such a file can be found here:

http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/LC81390452014295LGN00_B1.TIF

How can I read a TIF file in OCaml? Is there a library that already does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with a Landsat or other GeoTIFF image you may want to use bindings to GDAL for more complete support: https://github.com/hcarty/ocaml-gdal and http://gdal.org/

GDAL allows you to access the raw values and their geospatial information - location, projection and whatever else is included in the underlying TIFF.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used it in many years, but there is a library named [camlimages](https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/camlimages) that claims to support TIF files. You can install it with [OPAM](https://opam.ocaml.org).